# RSpec assigns(:items).should eq([item]) returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to RSpec, and obviously doing something wrong.

Have basic controller with Index action:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @transactions = current_user.transactions
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render layout: "items" } # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @transactions }
    end
  end
end
```

And have a default RSpec test for Index action.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe TransactionsController do
   describe "GET index" do
     it "assigns all transactions as @transactions" do
       transaction = FactoryGirl.create(:transaction)
       get :index
       assigns(:transactions).should eq([transaction])
     end
   end
end
```

So all works, except that the line `assigns(:transactions).should eq([transaction])` returns nil, so I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: assigns(:transactions).should eq([transaction])

   expected: [#<Transaction id: 1, user_id: 1, text: "some transaction", date: "2013-02-02", money: #<BigDecimal:b8a8e90,'0.999E1',18(18)>, created_at: "2013-02-02 09:17:42", updated_at: "2013-02-02 09:17:42">]
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/controllers/transactions_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Would appreciate any tips, as I've spent all day on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

firstly, if you use `before_filter :authenticate_user!` you need to pass that filter.

this could be done by using `sign_in some_user`

secondly, when you are assigning the transactions `@transactions = current_user.transactions`

and you expect that there should be some in the spec, you will have to create transactions that are ASSIGNED TO THE CURRENT USER `FactoryGirl.create(:transaction, user: some_user)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if get :index to controller.index works? If yes, you have to  check routes